# How to not create the nohup.out file, but keep the terminal output?

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, background-process, output, nohup

If you redirect the nohup application as:

```
nohup bash -c "printf \"command\n\"" &> /dev/null
```

The `nohup.out` file is not created, however the terminal I ran the command also do not get any output. How to keep the terminal output from the command but not create the `nohup.out` file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The point of `nohup` is to make the command run independently of the current terminal session (especially, to be able to keep running after the session ends). But if its output is going to the current terminal, and you close the terminal... how is it supposed to continue? What's supposed to happen in that case?

Comment: Then I just loose the command output, until I externally close the application and open it again with another terminal.

Comment: The command's output has to go *somewhere*. It could go to a terminal (tty device), to a file, to /dev/null, to a pipe being read by another program... but it has to go *somewhere*, and there's no mechanism for it to switch over (e.g. from the terminal to /dev/null when the terminal vanishes). I suppose you could write a program that'd copy from a pipe to a terminal until the terminal closes, then just discard input, but you'd have to write that program yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

To get the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` both on console and in a nohup.out file, execute the following before executing your `nohup` command.

```
exec >  >(awk '{ print $0; fflush();}' | tee -a nohup.out)
exec 2>  >(awk '{ print $0; fflush();}' | tee -a nohup.out >&2)
nohup bash -c "printf \"command\n\"" &
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the `nohup.out` to not be created, then try this

```
exec >  >(awk '{ print $0; fflush();}')
exec 2>  >(awk '{ print $0; fflush();}')
nohup bash -c "printf \"command\n\"" &
```

This will not create the `nohup.out` while displaying `STDOUT` and `STDERR` on the console.

Put the above lines in a script and then run it in the background.

Comment: I only want to nohup output on the console. I do not want it creating a file.

Comment: @user, Edited the answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it as follows

`nohup process & tail -f nohup.out`

Or use **tee** , which is util to do exactly what you need:
*read from standard input and write to standard output and files*

`nohup process 1>&2  | tee nohup.out &`

Comment: second give me `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`

Comment: I only want to nohup output on the console. I do not want it creating a file.

Comment: From the man page: "nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty". What are you trying to achieve exactly? You might need to use a different implementation

Comment: I am trying to keep the program running and let the terminal free to run commands while printing the program's output, but when I close the terminal I would like to not close the program